# Derivative of Function with Exponentials

Tags: derivatives

I would like to know the derivatives of the following function:

$ y = x^e*e^x$

At first sight it looks like the product rule should be used and so one would get $e*x^{e-1}*e^x+x^e*e^x$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Does $\ast$ denote product or convolution?

Comment: just product...

Comment: Sure, it's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes indeed, your answer is correct; you need only the product rule:

$$
\begin{align} y & = x^e\cdot e^x \\ \\ 
y' & = e \cdot x^{e-1}\cdot e^x + x^e\cdot e^x \tag{we can "factor" this}\\ \\
& = {\bf e} \cdot \color{blue}{\bf x^{e - 1} \cdot e^x} + {\bf x} \cdot \color{blue}{\bf x^{e - 1} \cdot e^x} \\ \\
& = {\bf(e + x)}\cdot \color{blue}{\bf x^{e-1}\cdot e^x} \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\tag{factored}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: You also need that the derivative of $e^x$ is $e^x$.